# Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.Create fails

Tags: glass-mapper

We upgraded from sitecore 7.2 to 8.2 and glass mapper from 4.0.9.60 to 4.4.0.199/4.4.1.331-beta. After upgrade, new SitecoreService("master").Create(folderItem, name, language) is failing with below exception messages. Below is full stack trace.
Resource class : https://www.dropbox.com/s/qu3qgneupw2xdym/Resource.cs?dl=0
GlassBase class: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lk8w4d66v20o32a/EWGlassBase.cs?dl=0

Exception messages:
1.Failed to find configuration for parent item type Sitecore.Data.Items.Item
at base.GlassContext.GetTypeConfiguration(parent, false, true)
2.The type Sitecore.Collections.ChildList does not contain any generic arguments
Sitecore Config: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xi8xy587k7krao2/ew%20norm.showconfig.xml?dl=0

> 15016 19:03:10 ERROR EW Exception on ItemService.Create. Path: /sitecore/content/EmpowerWomen/Home/Resources/Documents/2017/12, Name: testtest, Language: en.
>   Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException
>   Message: Failed to find configuration for parent item type Sitecore.Data.Items.Item
>   Source: Glass.Mapper.Sc
>   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.Create[T,TK](TK parent, String newName, Language language, Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
>   at UNWomen.SC.EW.Core.Services.ItemService.Create[T](String path, String name, Language language, Boolean useYearMonthFolders, Boolean checkDuplicatedName) in C:\Source\Repos\UNWSitecore\UNWomen.SC.EW.Core\Services\ItemService.cs:line 43
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: Glass.Mapper.MapperException
>   Message: The type Sitecore.Collections.ChildList does not contain any generic arguments
>   Source: Glass.Mapper
>   at Glass.Mapper.Utilities.GetGenericArgument(Type type)
>   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreChildrenMapper.Setup(DataMapperResolverArgs args)
>   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.DataMapperResolver.Tasks.DataMapperStandardResolverTask.Execute(DataMapperResolverArgs args)
>   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner2.<>c__DisplayClass8.<.ctor>b__1(T args) at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineTask1.Next(T args)
>   at Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner2.Run(T args) at Glass.Mapper.Context.ProcessProperties(IEnumerable1 properties)
>   at Glass.Mapper.Context.Load(IConfigurationLoader[] loaders)
>   at Glass.Mapper.Context.GetTypeConfigurationFromType[T](Type type, Boolean doNotLoad, Boolean checkBase)
>   at Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.Create[T,TK](TK parent, String newName, Language language, Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)

Comment: looks like the same problem: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2659/trouble-creating-content-item-using-glass-mapper-on-a-cd-server

Comment: thanks andrei. but this issue is happening in both CM and CD servers. added a link to the sitecore configuration file above for reference.

Comment: do you have [SitecoreParent]
public virtual BasePage Parent { get; set; } property in your glass base class?

Comment: Yes, we have that Parent property with [SitecoreParent] attribute in GlassBase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `folderItem` type should not be inherited from `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`(and `folderItem` should not be type of `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`).

It should be any your Glass Mapper model, but not inherited from `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`.

This issue was reported to [Glass Mapper GitHub and resolution is to use different parameters](https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/305).

Comment: Thanks Anton. We change it to one of the existing Glass base models and it worked. But if we try and use a different Glass model, it is not working. Let us know if there is any more information.